# how to stop navigating to other tab of bootstrap tabs on validating

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

i am validating tab one input fields on clicking on second tab

**please have a look on my html**

```
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs makeblock" role="tablist">
                                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#StuAdmn" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Admission</a> </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item" id="tabStudentGeneralDetails"> <a class="nav-link" href="#stuGenDetails" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General </a> </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#stuParentDetails" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Parent</a> </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#joingDetails" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Joining</a> </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#stuAdrs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Address</a> </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#feeDetails" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fee </a> </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div> 

//tab 1 div
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="StuAdmn">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <label for="firstName"><span>*</span>First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control only-alpha" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">

       </div>
</div>
//tab 2 div
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="stuGenDetails">
</div>
```

i am validation `id="firstName"` field on clicking on `id="tabStudentGeneralDetails"` tab i dont want to navigate to clicked tab until unless previous tabs tab fields are validated .

i have tried below code

```
$(document).on("click",".newSec #tabStudentGeneralDetails",function(e){
    var firstName=$(".newSec #firstName").val();
    if(firstName == "")
        {
        $(this).find("a").attr("aria-expanded",false);
            alert("Please enter student first name !"); 

        } 
});
```

by above code i can able to validate field of first tab but not able to stop moving to clicked tab when first tab data is inappropriate .

can any one help with this  ?

thank you.

Comment: Look at this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navs/#via-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap, the tab navigation can be activated in two different ways.

- You can specify `data-toggle="tab"` in your HTML to activate the tab navigation.
- You can activate manually using JavaScript with the help of `.tab()` function.

In your example, you have used the `data-toggle="tab"` method. This will activate the tab navigation automatically and you have limited control over its behavior.
In order to control its behavior based on some validation criteria, you need to used the second method to activate the tabs.

Please see the code below for a basic example. Here, I have removed the `data-toggle="tab"` from the HTML and used JavaScript to activate the tabs. I have defined an `isValid` function to check for form errors and the tab navigation will work only if the errors are resolved (in this case, enter some data in the input field).

```js
$('#myTab a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (isValid()) {
    $(this).tab('show');
  }
});

function isValid() {
  const text = $("#homeText").val();
  if (text.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    Home Tab Content<br>
    <input type="text" id="homeText" /> Enter some value
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile Tab Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact Tab Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding on to answer by Vivek, event.stopImmediatePropagation() would be more ideal in place of preventDefault() method.

Comment: Why would you say that ? @KevinSunny

Comment: @Vivek thank you for your answer but i am unable to stop navigation if its false .(not bale to override bootstrap's navigation)

Comment: @bharathvarma Make sure you have removed ```data-toggle="tab"``` from your html.